# using sparkr to connect to remote standalone spark

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I can use my standalone Spark installation on my remote box like this:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g"))
```

Just wondering, how can I access this standalone Spark installation from a remote machine. I think the port is 7077. So I currently try:

```
library(SparkR)
sparkR.session(master = "spark://NameOfVM:7077", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g"))
```

First of all I get an error along those lines:

```
Spark not found in SPARK_HOME
```

Do I really have to install Spark on my client box, although it is meant to run on a remote machine? Bit confusing ... Anyway, the above command appears to install Spark:

```
Installing to C:\Users\User1234\AppData\Local\Apache\Spark\Cache
DONE.
SPARK_HOME set to C:\Users\User1234\AppData\Local\Apache\Spark\Cache/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7
```

Why does the client of a remote standalone spark installation require the installation of spark?

After this I get:

```
Error in sparkR.sparkContext(master, appName, sparkHome, sparkConfigMap,  : 
  JVM is not ready after 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't need Spark running on your local machine, you do need a local installation so that you can use the spark-submit mechanism to launch your Spark App. Hence the need for SPARK_HOME.